# Creating default object from empty value when updating a record

Tags: php, laravel, object

I've a Carpenter Table that have primary key id, and other columns as Student Name, Description, Isfoward and HostelID(Foreign Key from hostel Table). It works well when I fetch all the record without **Join on Hostel** like beloww

```
public function View_NonForwardedCarpenterApp(){
    $carpenter_apps=CarpenterApps::join('hostels','hostels.id','CarpenterApps.HostelID')->where('Isfoward',0)->get();
       // $carpenter_apps=CarpenterApps::all();
        return view('Supervisor.CarpenterPendingApps', compact('carpenter_apps'));

          }
```

On Updating Isfoward it shows an error "**Creating default object from empty value**"

**Controller**

```
 public function ForwardCarpenterApps(Request $request, $id)
{
    switch($request->get('status'))
    {   
        case 0:
        
        $carpenter_app=CarpenterApps::find($id);
        $carpenter_app->Isfoward=0;
        $carpenter_app->save();
            break;
        case 1:
        $carpenter_app=CarpenterApps::find($id);
        $carpenter_app->Isfoward=1;
        $carpenter_app->save();
            break;
        default:    
            break;

    }
    //dd([$carpenter_app]);
    return redirect('/forwardedcarapps');
}
```

**View**

```
     <td><form method="post" action="{{ route('forwardcar', $carpenter_app->id )}}">
    @csrf
     <div class="row">
            <select name="status">
              <option value="" >Select Status</option>
              <option value="0" >Pending</option>
              <option value="1" >Forward</option> 
            </select>
        </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 7px;">
      
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</td>
```

Comment: `find` can return `null` (and is apparently)

Comment: how it can return null, when id is passing from view

Comment: because it can't find a record by what ever `$id` is it would seem ... since you are doing a join, perhaps you are getting the 'id' from the other table so its not the id of the record in the table you are trying to look up

Comment: then how to solve this problem, plz let me know

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you are getting the correct id field:

```
$selectedFields = ['carpenter_apps.id as id', ...] // and all your other required fields
$carpenter_apps=CarpenterApps::select($selectedFields)->join('hostels','hostels.id','CarpenterApps.HostelID')->where('Isfoward',0)->get();
```

To make sure it aborts 404 instead of throwing an error if cannot find the CarpenterApp:

```
$carpenter_app=CarpenterApps::findOrFail($id);
```